# name error in python and also what is indentation error in python?

Tags: python, python-idle

```
movies=["the holy grail",1975,"terry jones & Terry gilliam",91,
    ["gilliam chapman",["michael palin","john cleese","terry gilliam","eric idle","terry jones"]]]

for each_item in movies:
 if isinstance(each_item , list):
    for nested_item in each_item:
            if isinstance(nested_item , list):
                    for each_d in nested_item:
                            print(each_d)
 else:
    print(nested_item)
else:
    print(each_item)
```

when i am running this code in IDLE its giving error:-

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\sumit\Desktop\3d_array.py", line 12, in 
    print(nested_item)
NameError: name 'nested_item' is not defined

i dont know why this error is coming and also before that indentation error was coming and when i removed that error syntax error was coming for "else:" .Is it wrong systex of else?guys pls help me out.

Comment: Please format your code correctly. 4 spaces per each line will get it nicely formatted. You can use the previewer to help out.

Comment: Your indentation is all over the place. 1 space in some cases, 3 in others, 8 in others still. You could probably benefit from reading the [Python Style Guide](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)! :)

Comment: hey...thanks guys i got it....my indentation was wrong.i got it corrected thanx for ur help..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't tell how you have this indented from your post, but I think incorrect indentation is the problem, since the following code works:

```
movies=["the holy grail",1975,"terry jones & Terry gilliam",91, ["gilliam chapman",["michael palin","john cleese","terry gilliam","eric idle","terry jones"]]]

for each_item in movies:
  if isinstance(each_item , list):
    for nested_item in each_item:
      if isinstance(nested_item , list):
        for each_d in nested_item: print(each_d)
      else: print(nested_item)
  else: print(each_item)
```

Comment: A [`NameError`](http://docs.python.org/library/exceptions.html#exceptions.NameError) indicates that the object does not exist. In your example, on line 11, in the else, you're trying to print nested_item before it's even defined (it's defined only under the for loop).

Comment: @sumitkumarraj You're getting that error because, due to your indentation, the `else` statement that prints nested_item is associated with the `if isinstance` statement, and at this point, nested_item has not been defined.

Comment: @sumitkumarraj You need to fix your indentation.  There are several examples of properly indented code here--one's in my answer and the other answers all have some too.  Do any of these examples do what you want?

Answer (score 0):

You're going to have to format your example better, and you'll likely solve your problem in the process. Because `else:` can follow both `if` and 'for`, that code can be interprett]ed differently depending on how it's indented.

```
for each_item in movies: 
    if isinstance(each_item , list): 
        for nested_item in each_item: 
            if isinstance(nested_item , list): 
                for each_d in nested_item: 
                    print(each_d) 
            else: 
                print(nested_item) 
    else: 
        print(each_item)
```

versus:

```
for each_item in movies: 
    if isinstance(each_item , list): 
        for nested_item in each_item: 
            if isinstance(nested_item , list): 
                for each_d in nested_item: 
                    print(each_d) 
                else: 
                    print(nested_item) 
        else: 
            print(each_item)
```

There are other possibilities as well. Both of those work for me, and produce different results.

Meanwhile, if I understand your intent, you'll probably want to do something like the following instead:

```
def iterate_recursive(l):
    for item in l:
        if isinstance(item, list):
            for nested_item in iterate_recursive(item):
                yield nested_item
        else:
            yield item

for item in iterate_recursive(movies):
    print item
```

Which outputs:

```
the holy grail
1975
terry jones & Terry gilliam
91
gilliam chapman
michael palin
john cleese
terry gilliam
eric idle
terry jones
```

Comment: then how to do the indentation if i want to print the whole array.

Comment: hey...thanks guys i got it....my indentation was wrong.i got it corrected thanx for ur help..

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing all your tabs (if you have any) with spaces. That will make the indentation more clear.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another way to reduce your nested list to a single flat list, and it should work at all levels:

```
def reduce_recursive(x, y):
    if isinstance(y, list):
        return x+reduce(reduce_recursive, y, [])
    return x+[y]

for item in reduce(reduce_recursive, movies, []):
    print item
```

Comment: hey...thanks guys i got it....my indentation was wrong.i got it corrected thanx for ur help......